# powershell - emailmessage - attach every file of a filetype

Tags: email, powershell, attachment

I am trying to email each file of a certain filetype as an attachment. If I have
a single pdf the script works. However, many get created in a day. My script doesn't send each and every pdf in the folder when task scheduler runs. It only will take and send one file. This is part of the script. I have also tried "foreach ($createdproj in $sourcedir)

```
$sourcedir = 'E:\projectFolder'   
$createdproj = Get-Item -path 'E:\ProjectFolder\*.pdf' 

if ($createdproj ) {
$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.domain.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "25"
$emailSmtpUser = "user@domain.com"

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = "admin@domain.com"
$emailMessage.To.Add( "support@IT-Help.com" )
$emailMessage.Subject = "Project Successfully Created"
$emailMessage.Attachments.Add($createdproj)
$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
$emailMessage.Body = @"
<p>Here is a message states the csv was converted to pdf</p>
"@

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer ,        $emailSmtpServerPort )

$SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
```

}

Comment: I have also tried to filter the variable:
    $createdproj = get-childitem -path 'E:\ProjectFolder' -Filter *.pdf

Comment: Depending on how many files you are talking about it might make for a better experience for the end user if you zip the files and send the one zipped file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You. That worked. Here is the final:

```
foreach ($proj in $createdproj) {

$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.client.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "25"
$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = "system@client.com"
$emailMessage.To.Add( "support@ITcompany.com" )
$emailMessage.Subject = "Project Successfully Created"
$emailMessage.Attachments.Add($sourcedir + $proj.name)

$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
$emailMessage.Body = @"
<p>A CSV has been created and processed with information containing project    . </p>
"@

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer ,     $emailSmtpServerPort )

$SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried "foreach ($createdproj in $sourcedir)

Foreaching through $sourcedir will not get you all the items in the directory. You should know this since the very next line you get the files in the directory.

With your code the way it is, you should be able to

```
foreach ($proj in $createdproj) {
  $emailMessage.Attachments.Add($proj)
}
```